# First Order Logic formula related to describing POSET min/max? Is this correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic, order-theory

Does anyone know if this FOL formula correctly describes POSET min and max?

A description:

> A maximal element of a subset S of some partially ordered set (poset)
> is an element of S that is not smaller than any other element in S. A
> minimal element of a subset S of some partially ordered set is defined
> dually as an element of S that is not greater than any other element
> in S.

There is a POSET $R = (S, \subset)$

$maxes = \{x : x \in S \land (\forall y \in S (\lnot((x,y) \in R))\}$

or

There is a POSET $R2 = (S, \subseteq)$

$maxes = \{x : x \in S \land (\forall y \in S (\lnot((x,y) \in R2) \lor x = y)\}$
$maxes = \{x : x \in S \land (\forall y \in S (\lnot( x \subseteq y) \lor x = y)\}$

For the minimum:

$mins = \{y : y \in S \land (\forall x \in S (\lnot((x,y) \in R2) \lor x = y)\}$
$mins = \{y : y \in S \land (\forall x \in S (\lnot(x \subseteq y) \lor x = y\}$

Comment: What does $(x,y) \in R$ mean in the first formula? I guess you wanted to say $x \subset y$, because $\subset$ is the order relation under consideration.

Comment: This simply depends on whether you wish to consider the strict order (irreflexive), which is the first case, or the inclusive order (reflexive), which is the second case. Conventionally posets are taken to be reflexive unless specified otherwise. Note that $\neg P \vee Q$ is logically equivalent to the material conditional $P\rightarrow Q$ so that you could write "$\forall x\in S(x\subseteq y\rightarrow x=y)$".

Comment: The second set of formulae would also work in the irreflexive case of course

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco $(x,y)$ is the ordered pair that will exist in the binary relation R if $x \subset y$.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: @JudyN. I didn't see that!  Agreed!