# First Order Logic question on Axiom of Extensionality in Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

I have a FOL question on the set theory axiom of *Extensionality* added below.  I'm confused with the implication statement $\implies x = y$ which must be true if two sets have the same elements.  How is truth for the binary relation $x = y$ established?  Before evaluation of this form?

I know $x = y$ must evaluate to a truth value, but it seems the first argument to $\implies$ establishes this truth.  Why check if two sets have the same elements if the truth of $x = y$ is already known?

Perhaps I'm evaluating this incorrectly.

Axiom of extensionality:

$\forall x \forall y [\forall z (z \in x \iff z \in y) \implies x = y]$

Comment: iff symbol  also means  logically equivalence symbol

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are trying to say, but it sounds like you may be confusing this implication with its converse.

Comment: It's also very unclear what you mean by "establishing a truth".

Comment: @EricWofsey my confusion is the $x = y$ argument to $\implies$ is a binary relation which must evaluate to true if the sets have the same elements, yet establishing $x = y$ requires the first argument to $\implies$ be true. Is $x = y$ binary relation's truth established before evaluation of this FOL statement?

Comment: Equality is a primitive notion in first-order logic.  I again don't know what you mean by "establish".

Comment: In particular, without the axiom of extensionality, there is no rule of first-order logic that says that if $x$ and $y$ have the same elements, then $x=y$.  That's the whole point of the axiom of extensionaity--it's the axiom that tells you that.

Comment: @EricWofsey my confusion is about $x = y$ as the argument to $\implies$.  $x = y$ should evaluate true if the two sets have the same elements for the entire expression to be true.   When are the truth values for the arguments to $x = y$ defined?  Maybe I'm reading the FOL statement wrong and $x = y$ is true out of necessity for the entire FOL to be true?

Comment: this axiom can be written as $\forall x,y [x=y \iff (\forall z)(z\in x \iff z\in y)] $.Maybe this hepls you

Comment: As I said, equality is a primitive notion.  Intuitively speaking, it is assumed that you already know what it means for $x=y$ to be true, just like for $x\in y$.

Comment: From a purely syntactic perspective though (which is really the correct perspective when talking about axiomatic set theory as a foundation for mathematics), all of this is totally irrelevant.  Formulas aren't "evaluated" as truth values; they simply are strings of symbols.

Comment: @EricWofsey how is the truth of the formula not evaluated? The logical and relational symbols in this formula evaluate to a truth values including the quantifiers.  I know $x \in y$ because the domain of discourse would be defined to include a set with such a member.  I'm hung up on $x = y$ because I don't see that defined other then it must be defined out of necessity ($\implies$ argument) for the axiom to be true.  Does $\implies$ and the fact that the axiom must be true require that $x = y$ be define as true?

Comment: If you're talking about semantics (i.e., model theory), then your metatheory must have a notion of equality, and $=$ is interpreted as equality in the metatheory.

Comment: Perhaps what is confusing is that I'm asking if $x = y$ must be defined as a true relation to satisfy the axiom and you are bringing up definition of equality as primitive?  BTW, equality is not primitive in Bourbaki Theory of Sets where it is defined as $(T = U) \implies (R(T) \iff R(U))$

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the truth of $x=y$ is not necessarily already known. Suppose that $x=\{n\in\Bbb Z:n^2=1\}$ and $y=\{n\in\Bbb Z:|n|=1\}$; the definitions of $x$ and $y$ are both intensional, and they define $x$ and $y$ in terms of different properties, so in principle we could treat $x$ and $y$ as different sets. The axiom of extensionality says that it doesn’t matter what properties of its elements we use to define a sets, its identity is completely determined by its elements. Since my $x$ and $y$ have the same elements — they both correspond to the extensional definition $\{-1,1\}$ — we want to say that they are the same set, and it’s this axiom that lets us do so in the formal system.

Comment: My confusion is evaluating the FOL expression.  If the truth of $x = y$ is not necessarily known, how can the entire expression evaluate true for two sets with the same elements?  Does this mean that for the expression to be true we must define $x = y$ as true for the two sets?   Then, why check all the elements here unless it establishes that $x = y$ must be defined true out of necessity?

Comment: @Nick: It’s an axiom, so its truth value is known by definition.

Comment: If the axiom itself is known to be true by definition, does that mean $x = y$ is true out of necessity if the sets are equal?  I keep getting stuck on evaluating the logic of this FOL expression. Specifically observing that $\forall z(z \in x \iff z \in y)$ evaluates to true if elements of sets $x, y$ that are defined as equal, then arriving at the $x = y$ argument which must be true for such a case, then asking myself where x = y is defined.  Also asking myself if $x = y$ is defined true, wouldn't the first part of the implication be required to arrive at such a defn.

Comment: @Nick: No, it means that $x=y$ is necessarily true if $x$ and $y$ have the same members. Equality is taken as a primitive: $x=y$ means that $x$ and $y$ are identical, i.e., are the same thing. Of course one can also take FOL without identity as one’s formal system, in which case the axiom does become a definition of equality of sets.

Comment: That necessity of $x = y$ makes this understandable.  Would $x = y$ have to be defined as a true form somewhere to satisfy the axiom or does one automatically assert $x = y$ to satisfy?

Comment: @Nick: The axiom tells you that $x=y$ is true if $x$ and $y$ have the same members.

Comment: So I can use FOL to express axioms, which are true sequence of relations which may include a relation which is true out of necessity? I.e. $x = y$ which becomes true out of necessity.  I was also using FOL to express the minimum element of a POSET as follows $mins = \{y : y \in S \land (\forall x \in S (\lnot(x \subseteq y) \lor x = y\}$.  In this case the FOL expression may or may not be true, which is ok because it is not an axiom.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @Nick: Finally I see some of the confusion. You’re not using FOL to express $\min s$: you’re simply using some of the notation that is part of most presentations of FOL, along with a primitive symbol ($\in$) and some defined symbols (e.g., $\subseteq$) of set theory.

Comment: Interesting, the *min* is in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853050/first-order-logic-formula-related-to-describing-poset-min-max-is-this-correct?noredirect=1#comment7950372_3853050 which some folks confirmed as ok.  I thought $\in$ and $\subseteq$ are simply functions in FOL.  Is this wrong?

Comment: @Nick: Yes, it’s wrong. A FOL is a system that comprises a language, its syntax, and a semantics. At most those formulas use the language of the FOL commonly used for set theory, which has $\in$ as a primitive and $\subseteq$ as a defined symbol. They are compact ways of defining $\min$ and $\max$, but that’s all; they are not in themselves part of any particular logical system, any more than verbal definitions of $\max$ and $\min$ are.

Comment: I thought $\in$ and $\subseteq$ would be relational symbols in the signature?  Also, this axiom of extensionality stated here also uses $\in$.  Also, should I be defining *min* another way?  I was trying to define it without using the English language.

Comment: @Nick: Defining it symbolically without using the English (or any other natural) language is fine, but it has very little to do with first order logic: you’re just borrowing a handy and suitable symbolism.